# Just read new line in file csv using php

Tags: php, csv

In this case:

I have a `csv` file and program `php` file. php program file read data from `csv` file and insert to database, program `php` set interval to reload `csv` file every 5 seconds.

Question:

How do I create a `php` program that only reads new lines from the `CSV` file and inserts it to database without reading all the data in `CSV` again?

Comment: Keep track of the last offset you read from using `ftell` and `fseek`, store offset in the DB (like add it as part of the last saved row) then when you load the file start reading at that offset (after getting it from the db, such as `SELECT MAX(offset) as last FROM ..`) then use `fseek($offset)` to skip to that part of the file and read from there..  You can use SPLFileObject with uses line numbers instead of Bytes if you find it easier.

Comment: Of course if you showed some code it would be a bit easier to help you....

Comment: Additionally you could just wipe the file clean after reading the data and start from the beginning each time you read it.  But without knowing the source of said file and how it is created that's just speculation.  But is there really a need to keep that data after you put it in the DB?

Comment: you should save offset in database. when you fetch/get records from csv file thes used offset(that you save into dastabase) like this `//get 25 rows starting from the 11th row
$res = $csv->setOffset(10)->setLimit(25)->fetchAll();`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example

```
$f = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
$headers = [];

$offset = 0;
//select offset from DB

while(!feof($f)){
   if(empty($headers)){
      $headers = fgetcsv($f);
      if($offset) fseek($f, $last_offset);
      continue; //skip to the next iteration on header row
   }
   $data = fgetcsv($f);

   //combine 2 equal length arrays, with array1 as the keys and array2 as the values
   $row = array_combine($headers, $data);
   //get the file pointer offset to save in the DB row
   $current_offset = ftell($f);

   //save in DB

}
```

I didn't cover the DB part, but ftell, will give you the location of the file pointer in bytes.  This is where the read/write pointer is currently at.  Now when you save each row, add in a column named `file_offset` or something.  Don't use `offset` because its a reserved word in MySql

Then when you go to open the csv get the max offset in the DB such as this

```
  SELECT MAX(file_offset) as last_offset FROM table
```

Then after you pull the header row (this is a bonus I added) use `fseek` and that last offset as a starting point for this read attempt.

Simple.

Now if you don't like using byte offsets, then you can use the `SPLFileObject` class which can also read CSV, but it uses the line number instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php

http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php

I was going to hold of answering tell you posted at least a bit of code, but I see someone else answered.

So anyway, good luck.

Comment: I get the logic to solve my problem, i will try it later in my program. Thanks for your response and answer

Answer (score -1):

When you read the file first time, save the number of lines somewhere like session or a database table, and when you read the file next time, start reading the file from line number ahead of the number you saved previously. Then save you file data and increment the line number to the new value.

Comment: Got it, Thanks for your response and answer